# How to get value json

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to create an application

that saves video from Reddit

[This value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vik3b.png)

```
import UIKit


struct Country:Decodable {
    let fallback_url: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textUrl: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        }


    @IBAction func btnDownload(_ sender: Any) {

    let linkk = (textUrl.text!)

        let url = "\(linkk).json"
        let urlObj = URL(string: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) { (data, response, error) in

            do {


                let countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data!)

                for country in countries {
                    print(country.fallback_url)

                }


            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }


            }.resume()

    }



    }
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/acmuxu/parallax_table_view_header/.json

Please help me to read the value
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created `Codable` from the `JSON` you provided from [HERE](https://app.quicktype.io) And [HERE](https://app.quicktype.io?share=2O9jStiO6T444YFJc8F3) is the link with your `JSON`.

And you can get `fallback_url` below way from response:

```
@IBAction func btnDownload(_ sender: Any) {

    let url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/acmuxu/parallax_table_view_header/.json"
    let urlObj = URL(string: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) { (data, response, error) in

        do {

            let countries = try JSONDecoder().decode(Transactiondetails.self, from: data!)

            for country in countries {
                let childrens = country.data.children
                for child in childrens {
                    if let secureMedia = child.data.secureMedia {
                        let fallback_url = secureMedia.redditVideo.fallbackURL
                        print(fallback_url)
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error")
        }


        }.resume()

}
```

Check Out [DEMO](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=09457529922895801411) project for more info.

Comment: Happy to help you. :)