# How to Merge video with audio?

Tags: ios, swift

**How to Merge video.mp4 with audio.mp4 ?**

I download Reddit videos using the Swift App

[Videos downloading without sound](https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/9a16fv/videos_downloading_without_sound/)

I want code Merge video.mp4 with audio.mp4

Or

Convert audio.mp4 to audio.mp3

Comment: This is a requirement... not a question? just posting general requirements is not recommended, they are too broad. Please show your attempt and explain the issues with it

Comment: I downloaded the audio file and the video file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54049805/how-to-get-value-json

Answer (score 0):

you can Convert audio.mp4 to audio.mp3

```
let audioURL = ""
let outputUrl = ""

let asset = AVAsset.init(url: audioURL)

let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession.init(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality

exportSession?.outputFileType =  AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3


exportSession?.outputURL = outputUrl

exportSession?.metadata = asset.metadata

exportSession?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
    if (exportSession?.status == .completed)
    {
        print("succees")



    }
    else if (exportSession?.status == .cancelled)
    {
        print("cancelled.")
    }
    else
    {
        print ("Error is \(String(describing: exportSession?.error))")

    }
})
```